# autoresizing height of UiTableviewcell height with content

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I would like to update the content of my custom cell with his height so I wrote this code :

```
    extension MyViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return 100
    }
}
```

in my customCellTableView xib i added the top,right,left,bottom constraint to all the labels and also the numberOflines properties to 0
but when t run the app i got a cell of 250 height to all the cells which is very abnormal. I work on Xcode 9 and swift 4.
please if someone can help me,

Comment: Did you set the next to tableView?
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140

See here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: a added but nothing I get usually the same height 250

Comment: any help please